# Physical interpretation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-walk, graph-laplacian

I usually come across the eigenvalues of adjacency matrix or laplace matrix of a network. I know what their definitions are and how to compute them but I am unable to understand them intuitively what they actually stand for.

Can someone give some interpretation of eigenvalue or eigenvectors in a network and it's relation with mixing time of random walker in the network. I am facing trouble understanding the interpretation of these commonly used terms.

Comment: Have you read [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/26662/301977)?

Comment: @polfosol Yes, but I am looking for some interpretation for networks.